# AppVeyor settings for the build using GitHub

Tags: .net, msbuild, devops, cicd, appveyor

I have a question about AppVeyor, maybe someone uses it in conjunction with Github. I once set it up for one PET project, but recently rewrote it and now I've added several libraries to it, and the build is broken, I can't fix it. I don't know how to write a script for multiple solutions correctly. The link is [Build](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Ledrunning/tinnymonitor). Repository [link](https://github.com/Ledrunning/TinnyMonitor/tree/master/TinyMonitorApp).  There is only one thing more the script is located inside the directory with the main application. In the attached screenshot an arrow is pointing where the file appveyor.yml. Question number 2, where will it need to move?

Project tree:

[image]

Here is the current script:

```
image: Visual Studio 2022
branches:
only:
   - master

configuration: Release
environment:
major_version: 1
minor_version: 7
patch_version: 0
version: '$(major_version).$(minor_version).$(patch_version).{build}'
dotnet_csproj:
patch: true
file: 'TinyMonitorApp\TinyMonitorApp.csproj'
package_version: '$(major_version).$(minor_version).$(patch_version)'
assembly_version: '{version}'
file_version: '{version}'
informational_version: '{version}'

before_build: 
  # Display .NET version
  - cmd: dotnet --version
  # Display minimal restore text
  - cmd: dotnet restore
build_script:
  - cmd: dotnet build -c Release
artifacts:
  - path: TinyMonitorApp\bin\Release\TinyMonitorApp.exe
name: TinyMonitor

deploy:
release: tinymonitor-v$(APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION)
description: 'Release version'
provider: GitHub
auth_token:
   secure: token
artifact: /.*\.nupkg/            # upload all NuGet packages to release assets
draft: false
prerelease: false
on:
branch: master                 # release from master branch only
APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG: true        # deploy on tag push only
```